# Comparing covalent characters of two halides of group 15

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, covalent-compounds

Which is more covalent : NCl3 or PCl5 and why?
This question was asked on a test, and the given answer was NCl3. Shouldn’t PCl5 be more covalent since pentahalides are more covalent than trihalides?[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

Pentahalides are more covalent than trihalides **of the same element with the same halogen**. For instance $\ce{TaCl5}$ is more covalent than $\ce{TaCl3}$ (the respective WP articles give their melting points as [216°C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tantalum(V)_chloride) for the pentachloride and [440°C with decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tantalum(III)_chloride) for the trichloride); but we cannot make such a simple comparison of $\ce{TaCl5}$ with either $\ce{TaBr3}$ or $\ce{PCl3}$. Similarly the pentahalide/trihalide rule could be overriden by the difference between nitrogen and phosphorus in your case.